# Can't find /extras/google/play_billing folder for v3 billing walkthrough?

Tags: android

I'm trying to go through the v3 billing walkthrough here:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

I can't find the:

```
/extras/google/play_billing/
```

folder in my sdk location. The docs state:

```
"The sample files will be installed to <sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/."
```

I've got the latest:

[image]

But I do not see a folder named "play_billing" on disk. I do see one named "market_billing", though:

[image]

This was previously present when I was working with the original billing API. Are the instructions wrong, are we supposed to be using what's in "market_billing"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Google Play Billing you do not need that Google Play services. What you will download is just a sample project.

Will see this example for more details :
[Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)

I hope to have helped you!!

Comment: Huh, but that document says: "The sample files will be installed to <sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/.", which does not exist on my machine.

Comment: I don't understand why. Personally, I have : <sdk>\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive

Comment: Yeah I don't know either, maybe it's undocumented that if you already had the original billing folder, that one will just be used? Strange.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Scroll down to "Extras"
3. Put a check mark in "Google Play Billing Library". It should be installed already if   you're seeing the "market_billing" folder.
4. click Delete Package (make sure it's the only one checked)
5. After it's deleted successfully, it should say "Not installed" and the "market_billing" folder should be gone.
6. Put a check mark in "Google Play Billing Library" again and install it. Now you should have the "play_billing" folder.